# How inprocess asp.net hosting model working in Linux container

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, containers

Hi I am new to container. Thus asking this, may be a foul question.
The default hosting model of asp.net core is InProcess that requires IIS.
Now if we create an Linux image on a default asp.net core web app it is running and serving request.

I am confused here, how a Linux based image of .net core could serve InProcess hosting model

Comment: InProcess is a term that exists in IIS only.

Comment: I understand. But then with this inprocees setting how a Linux image running the asp.net core web app. I confused here

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research, it is evident to me that running application through dotnet CLI ignores the hosting model settings. The same could be seen as when running the application with dotnet run command from local machine. It then always returned response that could be seen be returned from kestrel no matter what is the hosting model settings.

Hope it will help other to understand the trick that could not see any where documented.